# What is the advantage to using an event-driven approach vs procedural programming?

Tags: oop, events, architecture, event-handling

What are the pros and cons of using an event-driven approach vs a non-event-driven (procedural) approach?

---

**Without EDP:**

Object A responds to some user input. Object A calls a method in Object B and a method in Object C and they perform their respective tasks.

**With EDP:**

Object A responds to some user input. Object A publishes an event in which Objects B and C are subscribed. Relevant data is packaged up into an EventArgs and received by B & C and they perform their respective tasks.

---

Is there an advantage to using one or the other? I'm at a crossroads where I need to choose. However, I do not have any objective information on which one is superior, and in what ways one may have an advantage over the other.

Thanks!

Edit: I am understanding the difference in a similar fashion to how it's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135353/3547347

Comment: It depends.  For example, what do you have to do when Object D is added the the system?  How often is that likely to happen?  Your design should be driven by your requirement.  And "game programming" is a bit too broad to comment further.

Comment: Your "event driven model" and "not event driven model" are both event driven models.  You just used different terms of describing identical behaviors.

Comment: Packaging relevant information into an object such as `EventArgs` is not inherent to the event-driven approach. It is just a design pattern which easily allows for forward-compatibility (adding of parameters) without breaking the public API.

Comment: To begin with, GUIs work with events (you do not have only "ObjectA" reacting to user input; all the controls in the GUI react to user input and you do not know which one will be the one that will be selected by the user).

Comment: I probably just have an elementary understanding of it. If you have Object A which then calls methods in Object B, C, D....etc Based off of some input. Versus Object A publishing event "ThingHappened" and not "knowing" or "caring" what other objects are subscribed to that event. How is that the same?

Comment: @douglasg14b You're just calling different objects by different names in each example.  In your "non event" driven example you say that `A` "responds to user input".  How does it do that?  It does it by handling an event.  In your "event driven model" A publishes events to B and C, in your "non-event driven model" an unnamed object is publishing events to A.

Comment: I'm writing this under the assumption that anything that happened before A is not relevant. The question would becoming increasingly long and complicated if I needed to go beyond it's scope and describe how data went from the keyboard to object A. Object A has a method that is subscribed to an event that's published from some sort of input in both examples. From there is where it changes, does it have a delegate which then has methods in other objects in it's invocation list. Or does it call methods from those objects directly. Then again, maybe I'm not quite getting where you're coming from.

Comment: I think rather than "event-based" vs. "non-event-based", you are inquiring about something like "loosely coupled" vs. "tightly coupled", or "runtime-bound calls" vs. "compile-time-bound calls".

Comment: Pros and cons: procedural programming is much simpler for sequential algorithms. Event-driven is easier to accomplish when non-sequential, unpredictable events must be handled. When do you write a set of driving directions and when do you use the controls of the car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an advantage to using one or the other?

Yes - using events *decouples* `A`, `B`, and `C`.  Without events, you cannot, for example, extend functionality by having *another* type respond to `A`s events without modifying `A`s code.

The downside is that it's harder to code (though not terribly) and you have to code more "plumbing" to add all of the relevent events.  It also makes it harder to trace logic since you don't know what may be listening to `A`s events at any one time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So If I understand correctly, decoupling A, B, and C makes it easier to extend functionality without modifying A's code. However, it makes the program more complex in the sense that you cannot just see the methods you are calling, you can just see that there is an event but it's a bit harder to see who/what is subscribed to that event. Not sure if this is bad practice or not, but could that logic tracing be made easier with a little documentation as I go?

Answer (score 1):

Extendability and maintenance. Instead of having to go back to the method and adding to it every time you want to add a new 'subscriber' in your without EDP example, you'll just add the method you want to call to its list of subscribers.

OOP is all about encapsulating the parts of your code that change, so that changing them has as few consequences as possible. You don't want to have to modify a vaguely related class each time you need new functionality elsewhere in a project.

So I would say given the two options, always go with the event driven model.

Comment: Having a type subscribe to an event and then call two different methods, instead of having those two methods each subscribe to the event, is not only still using an event driven model, but is quite appropriate in many instances (of course, not all instances).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about an observer pattern.

You use the observer pattern when you don't have an Object B and Object C at the time you are implementing Object A; or if you know that later, additional classes will need to know about the event, but you do not want them to have to modify the code for Object A.

Answer (score 0):

Event-driven programming is a concurrency model for handling IO bound process (like user input in your example).  So, really, both processes you've described are event-driven.

The difference between the two examples is that by introducing the publish / subscribe abstraction between the "observer" object and the "responder" objects you are, as D Stanley mentions, decoupling the two layers by adding a layer of indirection.

The advantage of this approach is greater abstraction (at the expense of just a little more complexity).  So you could do things like put a queue between the "observers" and the "responders" which can allow you to control and observe your process, and scale your system.

So, for example, Your "observer" could be a front-end application that queues jobs on to a queue server that is queried by the "responders" which are other applications that run on other servers. That would be one way to architect a multi-tier application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe using user input was a bad example? I understand that IO is almost always event handled. I'm talking about how the program responds after that. Lets say I click on a "unit". The click, it's location, and any objects it hit are packaged and published. You then have a method that responds to this and based on the location or object hit it calls methods in other objects which then do the same...etc Instead of calling objects in other methods, I would have it and other methods down the chain just publish and subscribe to events.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly the same principle applies.  If you want to have control over the cascade of events then put a queue between the "observer" and the "responders".  In effect you're making the kids wait patiently in line.  The queue could be an in memory data structure or it could be its own process like zero mq, or a home spun job queue built on a relational database.